# What would be the easiest way to get all user stories for a Portfolio Item in rally API?

Tags: rally

What would be the easiest way to get all user stories for a Portfolio Item in rally API? Right now, the API only returns the immediate children.

 **Similar to a previous question, is there any way to filter using the API in such a way as to get only the related User Stories?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently for performance reasons results from the WSAPI are are limited to one level of the hierarchy.  Once you have the immediate children from the results from your first query you will have to loop over each one and issue a new query for its children (and so forth recursively until you have only leaf children).

Are you doing this in an app?  It can be a little challenging to manage all the async callbacks and to stitch the data back together correctly but RallyDataSource should at least making the querying part simpler...

Comment: I am doing this as a custom app. I was hoping that this had already been done in one of the existing custom apps. Javascript is not one of my strong languages. Thanks though. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to get the nested US of a portfolio item using:  1.43 API version

```
                    queryFeat = "((PortfolioItemType.Ordinal = 0) and " + "(Release.Name != " + "\"" + selectedRelease + "\"))";
                console.log("queryfeat",queryFeat);



                queryArrayFeat[0] = {
                        key: CARD_TYPE,
                        type: 'PortfolioItem',
                        query: queryFeat,
                        fetch: 'Rank,FormattedID,Name,Release,Parent,GroomingState,LeafStoryCount,PercentDoneByStoryCount,LeafStoryPlanEstimateTotal,PercentDoneByStoryPlanEstimate,Project,Tags,ObjectID,Description,UserName,Children,Ready,Architect,SolutionTestArchitect,UserStories,Pipeline,PlanEstimate,SizeConfidence,Rank,Ready,Owner,Blocked,blockedReason,Release,Iteration,ScheduleState,ExecutionOrder,DoRCriteria,AffectsDocumentationTeam,HCSRoadmapItem,TopDownGroomAllUSCreated,State',
                        order: 'Rank'
                };
                queryArrayFeat[1] = {
                        key: 'users',
                        type: 'users',
                        fetch: 'UserName,ObjectID,DisplayName'
                };
                rallyDataSource.setApiVersion("1.43");
                rallyDataSource.findAll(queryArrayFeat, displayCards);
                console.log("Query Results:",queryArrayFeat);
```